# Javascript inconsistent behavior when website is deployed

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have an ASP.NET MVC website and the problem we have is this:

When the website is deployed, we see some strange Javascript related bugs, that never occur when running the website locally (on any of our computers).

**For example:**

1. An accordion menu opens and closes itself immediately when clicked, instead of just remaining open normally.
2. Some links that have their click event handled by Javascript suddenly ignore the event handlers, and just do nothing when clicked.

We have checked the files on our integration machine, and checked the build process many times, and we deploy the correct version of the files each time.

Where else could we check to fix this issue?

Any and all suggestions are welcome !

Thanks.

Comment: Please break this into two questions and show applicable code for each question.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the web developer tools / firebug console window? Can you check if all the js and css files have loaded for the page?

Comment: 1. make sure that you have deployed all the javascript files to the server and that they are correctly served. 2.It can be a race condition, where some code depends on the complete loading of other code residing in different javascript source files that are not completed downloading. This explains also why it works locally (faster downloads).

Comment: Fire up the Developer Tools in Chrome (hit F12 on your keyboard) and navigate to the site with problems. Do you see any errors printed on the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone !

We use [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/) for bundling our scripts, and as it turns out, I didn't notice that when we deploy, the cassette obtains one the the javascript files using a url.

That url pointed to a script we no longer use, and that was the cause for all of the weird bugs.

Thanks again.